# How to know is ExpandableListView parent item expanded?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to know is ExpandableListView parent item expanded? I'm making "not usual" realization of ExpandableList with buttons on it, that will expand\collapse parent item. And I don't see any boolean method that telling is this parent item expanded or not.

Answer (score 2):

You get the expanded/collapsed status in either getGroupView of the ExpandableListAdapter :

```
getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

or in the ExpandableListView call isGroupExpanded()

```
boolean isGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
```